# Как объединить похожие строки в массиве в одну PHP

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, php7

Есть двумерный массив неопределенного размера, вот его примерный вывод:

```
Array ( [id] => 3 [napryazhenie] => 220 [moshnost] => 0.8 [tip-nagryz] => ПП ) 

Array ( [id] => 2 [napryazhenie] => 380 [moshnost] => 0.8 [tip-nagryz] => ЧП ) 

Array ( [id] => 1 [napryazhenie] => 380 [moshnost] => 0.8 [tip-nagryz] => ЧП )
```

Есть необходимость объединить полностью похожие строчки по "napryazhenie", "moshnost", "tip-nagryz" в одну.
Есть array_unique

```
$execItems = $con->query("SELECT `id`,`napryazhenie`, `moshnost`,`tip-nagryz` FROM $usr ORDER BY id DESC");
$row = $execItems->fetch_assoc();
$result = array_unique($row);
print_r($result);
```

Вывод:

```
Array ( [id] => 3 [napryazhenie] => 220 [moshnost] => 0.8 [tip-nagryz] => ПП )
```

Но это поиск уникального

Вообще не понимаю как решить это. Подскажите, пожалста, буду очень благодарен!!!

Comment: А в sql не пробовали GROUP BY сделать по тем полям которые надо группировать?

Comment: @binliz тут не группировать надо, а уникальную выборку сделать. для этого `select distinct` пишут

Comment: @teran я как прочитал так и ответил  "объединить полностью похожие строчки" не замыслился, согласен, что можно distinct

Comment: и каков желаемый результат работы для этого примера ?

Comment: @binliz @teran Спасибо большое за помощь, решил вот так "SELECT `napryazhenie`, `moshnost`, `tip-nagryz`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `sasha` GROUP BY `napryazhenie`,`moshnost`,`tip-nagryz` HAVING `count` > 0"